# How to write a scraped data into dictionary using python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to write my scraped data into a dictionary using python. the format for the output is :

```
{'title' :{'author_name':{'price':150}},....}
```

can anyone give me an idea to do with python?

My_code:

```
def books():
   country = str(input('Enter the country:')
   driver = open_driver_connection()
   title = ['In Search of Lost Time','Ulysses','Don Quixote','The Great Gatsby','War and Peace']
   for lists in title:
            driver.get('url')
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, " search box").send_keys(lists)
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "xpath of the country in search box").send_keys(country)
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, " for submit").click()
            elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("list of websites for the best search")
            hrefs =[]
            for href in hrefs:
                driver.get(href)
                try:
                    try:
                        price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("").text

                    except:

                        price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("other path for few links").text

                except:

                    price = ("Price not mentioned")
                author_name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, " ").text
           driver.quit()
books()
```

I need to scrape the title, author_name, and the price in a mentioned dict format.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to use a dictionary. You would make an variable at the top (with country, driver, ...) you can name anything you want. For this example we name it books.

```
books = {}
```

if we want to add something to a dictionary we use dictionary[key]. So in your case you would get something that looks like this.

```
books[title] = {name:{price: 150}}
```

Do this for every book/title and you got your requirements.

Comment: got this error {'Error': TypeError("unhashable type: 'list'",)}

Comment: I think I made a mistake. I think what happens is that you put in title. And in your code you would need to do lists.

Comment: If you want to use dictionaries. This is the only option I think.